# Android Slices vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-slices

In latest Google I/O, google introduced Android Jetpacks, which have Slices.
Virtually its functionality looks same as Fragments,
So why I should prefer using Slices over Fragments, what is the usecase ?

Comment: Slice VS Fragment ? Well AFAIK Slices shows content from your app within the Google Search app . So there is is not comparison between these two . Please read [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/). Correct me if i am wrong  Anyone who is familiar with Slices .

Comment: Slices are not a replacement or an alternative solution for fragments instead they allow a way of interaction where you can provide concise and important content that your users might want

Comment: Thats correct. Slices are for the content which would be shown by Google services like Search, Assistance apps. Its has nothing to compare with Fragment. If you want to understand it, just goto google search for "schools near me". The first view like cards is Slice what we know in Android.

Comment: I would suggest you to read more about it in official documentations https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/

Answer (score 1):

`Slices` are totally totally different beautiful feature than fragments thats available from android 4.4 and up. `Slices` are UI snippet or a "slice" of UI from a third-party app that will show up in the search result when a certain search parameter is entered in the search bar.

For eg when you search for some actions like "Fastest way home" then a snippet of UI from your app can show up in the search result with a snapshot of the map showing the route to home.
Note this shows up in the search result directly(which is an app by itself) and it shows the UI you have set up in your app to show up.

Simply put Slices enable apps to share their functionality in the form of screen elements.

Here is more details about slices and how to get started with slices [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/)

This image shows when 'lyft' was searched it shows a slice from lyft app exposing its functionality.

[image]